# RabbitMQ persist last message for specific routing key

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm in the process of restructuring my home automation and am aiming to use RabbitMQ as the central entry point for data (weather, lights, heating, ...), moving away from REST.

Messages have the following structure

```
routing key: mcu.le.d8.w1.terrasse.BA1
{
  "DS18B20": {
    "T1": 14.75,
    "T2": 14.56
  },
  "HYT221": {
    "H": 73.2,
    "T": 14.23
  },
  "LDR": 53,
  "T": 14.66
}
```

or

```
routing key: weather.wetter.now
{
  "from": "19:30",
  "from-ts": 1508347800,
  "local": "2017-10-18 19:59:00",
  "sunrise": "07:49",
  "sunrise-ts": 1508305740,
  "sunset": "18:27",
  "sunset-ts": 1508344020,
  "temp": 14.1,
  "text": "klar",
  "wind-direction": 270,
  "wind-speed": 2.5
}
```

with additional data such as where this data comes from and when it got generated.

All this data gets pushed into one single topic exchange, where clients bind to with exclusive, auto_deleting queues.

What I want is that when a new client connects and creates/binds a queue, that the last message for each routing key is sent to the client, so that the client obtains an up-to-date state of every routing key it subscribes to upon subscribing.

An alternative would be to create a client that subscribes to all and inserts it into a database, and the client queries the database first to get the snapshot, and then starts listening to updates from RabbitMQ.

Is there a way to do this without a database, only in RabbitMQ? I don't want to store all the messages, only the last one for each routing key.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need the exchange to persists messages and I do not think that is possible in Rabbit. The flow, as I understand it, is the exchange receives a request and forwards that message to all subscribed queues. If you do not have a queue subscribed, the message would be lost.

If you really want to avoid the db and don't mind a bit of a unique implementation, you could create a backup queue per message type and before publishing, read and **acknowledge** the message from the respective backup Q, and then when a new client comes in, you can read **without** acknowledging so that message will remain for another future client or until acknowledged by the publisher. This probably is more complex then storing to a db though...

P.S. sounds like you have a cool project going on.  If you plan to put it on Instructables please send me a link.

Answer (score 0):

*Rabbit MQ* does not have this concept (was mentioned over 10 years ago as planned, still not implemented). *AMPS* does, though - it's called "the state of the world".
http://devnull.crankuptheamps.com/documentation/html/5.2.1.0/user-guide/html/chapters/sow.html